# sbt gives "configuration not public" for depending on test in subproject

Tags: sbt, multi-project

I have an sbt multi-project build, which works fine locally. It uses an external ivy settings file, and on my machine I have the sbt inter-project resolver added to my ivy settings file. However, when I build on Jenkins, I'd like to build *each subproject separately*, so that I can independently release each subproject. So on the Jenkins server, I have not included the inter-project resolver in the ivy settings file.

The problem is, I have my main subproject configured in `project/Build.scala` with:

```
dependsOn(common % "test -> test; compile -> compile") aggregate(common)
```

and I get the following exception:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.company.team#foo-common_2.10;0.1: configuration not public in com.company.team#foo-common_2.10;0.1: 'test'. It was required from com.company.team#foo_2.10;0.2 test
at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1144)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1142)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1165)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1163)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1167)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1162)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1170)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1135)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1113)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is it possible to have one build file which works in both scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned on test publishing?

> publishArtifact in Test := true

see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts.html

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've put the inter-project resolver back in to the ivy settings file, and I'm relying on developers to manually build from the right branch, so that they (re)compile the right version of the subproject being depended on (`common`).