# TeamCity can't resolve test artifact from Nexus with "configuration not public" error

Tags: sbt

This is similar to [sbt gives "configuration not public" for depending on test in subproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700261/sbt-gives-configuration-not-public-for-depending-on-test-in-subproject) but we don't have an external Ivy file. We have

```
lazy val core = "com.huawei.scalan" %% "core" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT" % "compile->compile;test->test" 

lazy val enterprise = Project(
  id = "enterprise-edition",
  base = file(".")
).configs(ItTest).settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(core))
```

The dependency is taken from our Nexus repository, set up as described in http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html. This works fine for developers' builds, but TeamCity, running on the same machine, produces an error:

> [warn]    :: com.huawei.scalan#core_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT: configuration not public in com.huawei.scalan#core_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT: 'test'. It was required from com.huawei.scalan#enterprise-edition_2.10;0.2-SNAPSHOT test

It certainly accesses the correct repository, since it retrieves the `compile` configuration without problems. SBT version is 0.13.5. In the process of writing this question I found a workaround: write dependency as

```
lazy val core = "com.huawei.scalan" %% "core" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

...
  settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(core, core % "test" classifier "tests"))
```

So the question is more why the previous configuration doesn't work for TeamCity and *does* work when `publishLocal` is used.

Comment: Quick questions:  (1) What sbt version? (2) Publishing as ivy or maven pom.xml?  

This looks very much like an issue translating pom.xml into the ivy universe for test->test dependencies (maven has no notion of thiis, it only has classifiers).   I've recently done work here, but we could be missing some aspects you need.   Another workaround would be to publish as ivy.xml (if you're not already).   If you are publishing as ivy, it's a more serious bug.

Comment: @jsuereth 1) 0.13.5; 2) Publishing as pom.xml (and `publishLocal` talks about Ivy, so this does seem like a possible difference source).

Comment: very likely an ivy-maven issue.  If you start publishing ivy.xml to nexus do you see the issue?

Note:  some Ivy/maven fixes are included in sbt 0.13.7-M2/0.13.7-M3.  It's not out yet, but you should try it out and see if it helps.  I think it won't, but we *did* try to issue a few corrections around configurations + maven.

Comment: @jsuereth I get a similar issue with sbt and "test->test". Switching from 0.13.5 to either 0.13.6 or 0.13.7-XX causes a "...configuration not public in organization#projectname_2.11;0.0.XX: 'test'...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [sbt issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1827) seems to explain it: this would be a consequence of trying to get a test dependency if the same version has been resolved out of a public Maven repository.

A workaround would be using git SHA versioning or SNAPSHOT for non final builds.